# Error in React Application trying to bind to view

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React, I am getting data from an API and then trying to display that data, I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function
```

**`Component.js`**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../about/about.css';

class About extends Component {

    state = {
        loading: false,
        data: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ loading: true })
        console.log('app mounted');
        fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=8ee8c21b20d24b37856fc3ab1e22a1e5')
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ data, loading: false }))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="about">
                {this.state.loading
                    ? "loading..."
                    : <div >
                        {this.state.data.map(post => {
                            return (
                                <div className="container about text-left mt-5" key={post.id}>
                                    <div>
                                        <h5>{post.title}</h5>
                                        <p>{post.description}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}

                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default About;
```

Api data schema is:

```
{
"status": "ok",
"totalResults": 70,
-"articles": [
-{
-"source": {
"id": "cnn",
"name": "CNN"
},
"author": "Chris Isidore, CNN Business",
"title": "FedEx problems go beyond its split with Amazon - CNN",
"description": "FedEx and Amazon have been going through a very public divorce. But that's not the biggest problem for iconic delivery company.",
"url": "https://www.cnn.com/2019/12/18/business/fedex-amazon-outlook/index.html",
"urlToImage": "https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/191218141028-01-fedex-delivery-truck-0807-super-tease.jpg",
"publishedAt": "2019-12-18T22:08:00Z",
"content": null
},
-{
-"source": {
"id": "cbs-news",
"name": "CBS News"
},
"author": "Aimee Picchi",
"title": "Downward tilting toilet is designed to shorten your bathroom break - CBS News",
"description": "StandardToilet's seat angles toward the floor, making it uncomfortable to sit for more than a few minutes.",
"url": "https://www.cbsnews.com/news/downward-tilting-toilet-may-cut-down-on-long-bathroom-breaks/",
"urlToImage": "https://cbsnews3.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/r/2019/12/18/a6ad8eb9-6084-4299-9289-3e0c269697de/thumbnail/1200x630/725f98269da8d5b25032449ebbb3e1ee/standard-toilet-no-1002.jpg",
"publishedAt": "2019-12-18T21:45:00Z",
"content": "Your bathroom break may soon become less comfy — and shorter — due to a new downward-tilting toilet aimed at making it tough to sit for more than five minutes. \r\nStandardToilet, based in the U.K., claims people spend 25% more time in office bathrooms than nec… [+1826 chars]"
},
-{
-"source": {
"id": null,
"name": "Jalopnik.com"
},
"author": "Kristen Lee",
"title": "Delta's New Uniforms Are Giving Attendants 'Skin Lesions, Fatigue, Migraines, Hair Loss': Report - Jalopnik",
"description": "Delta’s crew of flight attendants are easily distinguishable because of their deep purple and gray uniforms. But a recent, nightmarish report from Business Insider asserts these uniforms might be the cause of mysterious illnesses and ailments among Delta empl…",
"url": "https://jalopnik.com/deltas-new-uniforms-are-giving-attendants-skin-lesions-1840512868",
"urlToImage": "https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/c_fill,f_auto,fl_progressive,g_center,h_675,pg_1,q_80,w_1200/ivuzhac1dhgnfmr4fuy8.jpg",
"publishedAt": "2019-12-18T21:20:00Z",
"content": "Deltas crew of flight attendants are easily distinguishable because of their deep purple and gray uniforms. But a recent, nightmarish report from Business Insider asserts these uniforms might be the cause of mysterious illnesses and ailments among Delta emplo… [+4104 chars]"
},
-{
-"source": {
"id": null,
"name": "Yahoo.com"
},
"author": null,
"title": "Micron beats quarterly earnings estimates on higher memory demand - Yahoo Finance",
"description": "Shares of Micron rose nearly 4% in extended trading, after its quarterly earnings beat Wall Street estimates on an uptick in demand for memory chips after a tepid year.  \"We applied for, and recently received all requested licenses that enable us to provide s…",
"url": "https://finance.yahoo.com/news/micron-beats-quarterly-revenue-estimates-211255200.html",
"urlToImage": "https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/uqwJlBivrBy.2phwMZzj9w--~B/aD01MzM7dz04MDA7c209MTthcHBpZD15dGFjaHlvbg--/https://media.zenfs.com/en-US/reuters-finance.com/7256e2d01a13c4018bd074ee85d85267",
"publishedAt": "2019-12-18T21:12:00Z",
"content": "(Reuters) - Micron Technology Inc said on Wednesday it had received all requested licenses to supply some products to its largest customer, China's Huawei, a huge relief for the chipmaker that has been struggling amid a slowing memory market.\r\nShares of Micro… [+2000 chars]"
},
-{
-"source": {
"id": null,
"name": "Marketwatch.com"
},
"author": "Mark DeCambre",
"title": "One of the most successful stock-market investors says these 3 events ‘would definitely trigger a bear market’ - MarketWatch",
"description": "Stanley Druckenmiller, one of Wall Street’s most successful investors, acknowledges that the markets are riding high and that investors may be able to...",
"url": "https://www.marketwatch.com/story/one-of-wall-streets-most-successful-investors-says-these-3-events-would-definitely-trigger-a-bear-market-2019-12-18",
"urlToImage": "http://s.marketwatch.com/public/resources/MWimages/MW-HK736_drucke_ZG_20190604073854.jpg",
"publishedAt": "2019-12-18T21:04:00Z",
"content": "Stanley Druckenmiller, one of Wall Streets most successful investors, acknowledges that the markets are riding high and that investors may be able to finally breathe freely in the short term after a number of shocks, but says investors should be wary of three… [+3137 chars]"
},
-{
-"source": {
"id": null,
"name": "Newsbtc.com"
},
"author": null,
"title": "Why Bitcoin is Perfectly on Track for Parabolic Cycle Despite 50% Drop - newsBTC",
"description": "Analysts are noting that Bitcoin may be positioned for further gains in the near-term, as BTC's parabolic trend cycle has still remained firmly in tact.",
"url": "https://www.newsbtc.com/2019/12/18/why-bitcoin-is-perfectly-on-track-for-parabolic-cycle-despite-50-drop/",
"urlToImage": "https://www.newsbtc.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/shutterstock_547238893-1200x780.jpg",
"publishedAt": "2019-12-18T21:01:31Z",
"content": "Bitcoin experienced a sharp and sudden drop earlier this morning that led the crypto as low as $6,400, and its reaction to this level has provided some much-needed validation for embattled bulls who feared that BTC would experience significantly further losse… [+2766 chars]"
},
```

etc etc

Any idea's?

Comment: It looks like you have a race condition you aren't handling. Is the API call successfully updating state?

Comment: no the app just hangs and `throws error`

Comment: you should add your state in constructor 
`constructor(props) {
        state = {
            loading: false,
            data: []
          }
      }`

Comment: @PunitPatel where would I need to put this?

Comment: State which you have defined that should be wrap in constructor.

Comment: @Sole please check answer section for more idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.then(data => this.setState({ data, loading: false }))` prolly this. for map to work the structure of `this.state.data` should be array. It seems you're overriding your data state with the data json.

I assume you want to extract articles? `data: data.articles` on the same line if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Correct `data.articles

Comment: Can you be abit more clear about where the code would be implemented?

Comment: basically instead of `this.setState({data, loading: false})` do `this.setState({ data: data.articles, loading: false})`